# My headphone only shows connected voice

Tags: headphones

[image: img1]

It doesn't show voice and music , which means I cannot connect to stereo.

img2
[image]

But sometimes I still see it. Whenever I want to use stereo I have to turn off and on my headphones many times, but it's still working well when using mobile.

Comment: It's a Bluetooth device. Profiles are typically managed in Bluetooth settings, not directly at sound settings.

Comment: could you give me more details